# How to write lengths of time in a short way with numbers

Tags: time, measuring-units

I am writing statistics results and I want to put a list of *lengths of time*.

In decimal values it will be, for example, `1.90 hours` but this is not very human friendly.

Then I think I can use `1 hour and 54 minutes` but it is very long and difficult to compare with other lengths of time.

I would like to have something like: `1:54` but I don't know how to express the units. Would it be `1:54 hours` or would it be `1:54 minutes`? both feel wrong.

Comment: fairly typical is 1h54m

Comment: You could say 114 minutes.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry your suggestion sounds right, can you create an answer with it?

Comment: It also depends on your target market.  For example, English speakers would probably prefer 12:34:56, whereas I believe Holland/Netherlands, prefer 12h34m56.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [W3 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) uses:

> hh:mm:ss

For simple timestamp, with no seconds, try:

> 1h54m

or:

> 01h54m

Both are readily parsed by a computer due to the h and m and indicating the end of the numeric.

Comment: You can also put 1:45, although that's sometimes confused for "an hour and forty-five minutes after noon/midnight," depending on context.

Comment: @MissMonicaE That's the difference between "time" and "duration". They shouldn't be confused if you know what you're looking at, and anything that's meant to be one, shouldn't be labeled the other.

Comment: @fredsbend Right, I'm saying that hours:minutes (or minutes:seconds) notation can be used for duration as well, depending on context. For example, if I said I ran a 4:30 marathon, that means I finished in 4.5 hours, not that the race started or ended thirty minutes past four o'clock.

Answer (score 3):

ISO8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) has a section on periods, so things like "P1D" represents one day, or "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

Comment: This is probably easy for a computer to parse, but as a human, if I saw that, I would have *no clue* what the duration represented (and I suspect the vast majority are not familiar with ISO8601). If an audience is familiar with the standard, it might be a good solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be VERY careful when using time. For example,

1:54 could mean

- 01:54 AM - A time
- 13:54 PM - A time
- 1 hour 54 mins. - A duration
- 1 min. 54 seconds - A duration
- 1 out of 54 - a ratio
- probably many others

So your best bet is to know your target audience. For example office workers that always work 9am to 5pm will see 1:54 is 1 hour 54 mins. after 12 - noon. While an audio editing team of people may see it as 1 min, 54 seconds.

So, that leaves us with a few options if your trying to get everyone to understand.

1.90 hours is a good start.
1h54m is decent
01:54:00 is good too
01:54.00 is good
I would choose, personally

114 mins.

or

two columns

```
Hours | Mins  
1     | 54
```

Both are easy on the computer and hard to misunderstand.

Comment: I would read "01:54.00" as "1 minute, 54 seconds, and no hundredths of a second"

Comment: 1.90 hours is a _bad_ start. I have never in my whole life seen anyone write a duration using decimal fractions of an hour. Mixing colons and periods is bad for exactly the reason @warren gives.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see decimal parts of hours a lot